# Call ServeHandler from main function

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore, python-2.5

I'm trying to pass parameter from python page to another through the URL,this parameter(key in my problem)is passed correctly but in the other page i have this code:

```
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
import urllib
import urllib2        
class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self):

          blob_key = self.request.get('key')
          blob_key = str(urllib.unquote(blob_key))
          blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key)
          self.send_blob(blob_info)

def main():

     application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
    [('/',ServeHandler),], debug=True)
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but the problem that class `ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):`didn't execute ,when i ran this code, the output is

```
Status: 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

although the parameter is passed correctly;this is the url and the key(parameter):

```
http://localhost:8080/download.py?key=vzsX4xM1EtNak5RQVxj4BQ==
```

EDIT:
This is my app.yaml code:

```
application: myapplication
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /compress.py
  script: compress.py
- url: /download.py
  script: download.py
- url: /decompress.py
  script: decompress.py
- url: (.*)/
  static_files: static\1/index.html
  upload: static/index.html
```

Please i want a solution for this problem ?any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: what does your `app.yaml` look like?

Comment: dear god, man; please add that information to your question (edit it)

Comment: @bernie:Ok i will edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/download.py` isn't even in your `app.yaml`.
How would `webapp` find the correct script to run?

Concentrating for now on the download script, this is an example of how your `app.yaml` should look:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: download.py
```

---

Edit:
Alternatively, you can specify a more-specific regexp-pattern for the download URL:

```
def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
            (r'/download.*', ServeHandler),
        ], debug=True)
```

And the URL would be something like:

```
http://localhost:8080/download?key=vzsX4xM1EtNak5RQVxj4BQ==
```

Comment: :Thank you,but if i put this as you write in app.yaml,then the main page will executed as (download.py)page and my project has 3 python page and one html file as shown above in app.yaml?

Comment: A valid concern. I will update answer. But it will require one more step on your part. Hang in there.

Comment: :Thanks very much for your help,now the class is executed.